# Example Sylow Subgroup of $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have been given the problem of determing $n_2(A_5)$.

I do not want the answer to this, since I am making some progress by myself. The issue is, I have run into what seems like a contradiction, and I can't figure out where I went wrong.

We start by observing that $|A_5|=60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. This means that any Sylow 2-subgroup is going to be of order 4. Furthermore, properties of $A_5$ let us conclude that there are no elements $\tau \in A_5$ with $|\tau|=4$.

Therefore, we conclude that none of the Sylow 2-subgroups of $A_5$ are cyclic. Thus, each one is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. Since the only elements of $A_5$ are pairs of disjoint 2-cycles, I wrote out the 2-subgroups as follows:

$$
P = \{1, (a\ b)(c\ d),(a\ b)(e\ f),(c\ d)(e\ f)\}
$$
for distinct $a,\dots,f$, since this will satisfy the properties for the Klein 4-group. However, we are working in $A_5$, so we can't actually pick distinct $a,\dots,f$ to construct this.

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Why do you assume the elements of $P$ have to share cycles?

Comment: Thanks, this comment was sufficient to help me realize my mistake.

Comment: In fact, $A_4$ has a *normal* subgroup of order $4$, which gives you an obvious subgroup of order $4$ in $A_5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutation groups are highly non-commutative. If you choose any two permutations in random, then they do not commute. In particular, if you are picking two permutations of the type $(a,b)(c,d)$, then they may not commute, hence do not fall in the (abelian) $K_4$ group. What should be done?

Note that $A_5$ has 5 copies of $A_4$: each copy is obtained by considering all the even permutations which fix a given letter.

Then, in each $A_4$, you have Sylow-$2$ subgroup - it is $K_4$.

This give all the Sylow-$2$ subgroups of $A_5$ (can be proved by some group-action argument or other way one thinks.)